# Singleton with async initialization

Tags: javascript, promise, singleton

I have a use case where a Singleton object has an asynchronous step as part of its initialization. Other public methods of this singleton depend on an instance variable that the initialization step sets up. How would I go about making an async call synchronous?

```
var mySingleton = (function () {

  var instance;

  function init() {

    // Private methods and variables
    function privateMethod(){
      console.log( "I am private" );
    }

    var privateAsync = (function(){
      // async call which returns an object
    })();

    return {

      // Public methods and variables

      publicMethod: function () {
        console.log( "The public can see me!" );
      },

      publicProperty: "I am also public",

      getPrivateValue: function() {
        return privateAsync;
      }
    };
  };

  return {

    // Get the Singleton instance if one exists
    // or create one if it doesn't
    getInstance: function () {

      if ( !instance ) {
        instance = init();
      }

      return instance;
    }

  };

})();

var foo = mySingleton.getInstance().getPrivateValue();
```

Comment: `How would I go about making an async call synchronous?` - that's unpossible

Comment: What is expected result of `var foo = mySingleton.getInstance().getPrivateValue()`?

Comment: This is just a complicated version of how you can't return from an asynchronous method, and boy did you complicate something inherently simple.

Comment: **Disclaimer:** Singletons are awful. Do not use them, they don't solve anything - just use a regular object and pass it around. The methods of that object should return a promise which can chain the initialization step.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, I'll probably try something like this. Thanks. As I I was coding, this pattern seemed kinda overkill anyway.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - ok... so can you explain why you said that? ...

Comment: @nf071590 http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - hmmm... you realize that is a link to a java example and this stack overflow question is for javascript? So I am sorry,  but I cannot distinguish your point... and it seems like in that example they just have classes that reference other classes (or are dependent on...) within their implementation details (without any documentation to cross-reference each other) and I don't think that's what a singleton is... please correct me if I am wrong - I am not a java expert (or singleton for that matter.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to use an IIFE to create a somewhat singleton-like approach, you still have to use promises or callbacks with async calls, and work with them, not try to convert asynchronous to synchronous

Something like

```
var mySingleton = (function() {

  var instance;

  function init() {
    // Private methods and variables
    function privateMethod() {
      console.log("I am private");
    }

    var privateAsync = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          // async call which returns an object
        // resolve or reject based on result of async call here
    });

    return {
      // Public methods and variables
      publicMethod: function() {
        console.log("The public can see me!");
      },
      publicProperty: "I am also public",
      getPrivateValue: function() {
        return privateAsync;
      }
    };
  };

  return {

    // Get the Singleton instance if one exists
    // or create one if it doesn't
    getInstance: function() {

      if (!instance) {
        instance = init();
      }

      return instance;
    }

  };

})();

var foo = mySingleton.getInstance().getPrivateValue().then(function(result) {
   // woohoo
}).catch(function(err) {
    // epic fail
})
```

Comment: I will try this, along with another approach suggested in the comments above.